# Filter DELETE REST API calls

Tags: rest-api, permissions, wp-delete-post

I have a custom post type, that can be editable by more than one user.
Each post of that type has a field with the user ids who can edit it (kinda like co-authors).
But since many users have permissions to the post, I am not sure how to prevent deletion by other users (not in the co-authors' list).

Right now the problem is only present in the REST API which is used to delete from the frontend.

**Is there a pre delete hook in which I can check for permissions and block the deletion if the user is not allowed to delete that specific post?**

Comment: Have you tried the `pre_delete_post` hook? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_post/

Comment: you could also tackle this via the capability filters, avoiding needing to deal with anything REST API related at all

Comment: @geouser I have thought about it but did not know how to stop the deletion if need be

Comment: @TomJNowell I am not sure how this can be done for every post has different authors.

Comment: There are filters that let you do this on a per post basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre_delete_post` hook filters whether a post **deletion** should take place. So callback function must return a boolean value: `true` - whether to go forward with deletion, `false` - if not.

`pre_trash_post` hook filters whether a post **trashing** should take place. So callback function must return a boolean value: `true` - whether to go forward with trashing, `false` - if not.

```php
add_filter( 'pre_delete_post', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'pre_trash_post', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );

function filter_function_name( $delete, $post ) {

    // You have a field with user IDs for the post, get them as array of IDs
    $authors = array(1, 2, 3);
    
    // Get current user ID, who attempts to delete the post
    $current_user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    
    // make a check if the current user ID is among the co-authors IDs
    if ( !in_array( $current_user_ID, $authors ) ) {
        // If so, return false to prevent post deletion
        return false;
    }
    
    // else do nothing, and return default value
    return $delete;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the answer to explain how it answers? At the moment it's just a code snippet with no explanation, the OP might not know that modifications need to be made to get the co-authors

Comment: Thank you @geouser for a very informative answer. However, I seemed to have stumbled upon another problem. Using your code the filter_function_name is not being called at all

Comment: @CaptainNemo I've edited the answer. You also need to run this function for the `pre_trash_post` hook too. Tested it in REST API, and it prevents the post from being deleted or moved to trash

Comment: Works like a charm.